# how can I align textview in Constrainlayout

Tags: android, textview, alignment, android-constraintlayout

> I am developing news app but I am not able to align textview so that
>   it is overlapping around imageview how can I show it properly
>   I am developing news app but I am not able to align textview so that
>   it is overlapping around imageview how can I show it properly
>   below  my xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.55"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/articleImage"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/articleAuthor"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Placeholder"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/articleAuthor"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/articleAuthor"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Secondary"
        android:id="@+id/articleTitle"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/articleTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/articleAuthor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Tertiary"
        android:id="@+id/articleTime"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/articleTime"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/articleTime"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/articleTime"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/articleShare"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/articleFavorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/articleShare"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/articleShare"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/articleShare"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bookmark"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

below current screenshot of app[image: current screenshot of the app]

below screenshot which I want to achieve
[screenshot I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rkpc.png)

Comment: Do you want the text to wrap before the left edge of the image view, but then flow underneath the image view if the text is really long and winds up taller than the image view? Or do you just want to make sure the text is all in one column to the left and the image is in another column to the right?

Comment: I want to show textview on the column properly

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to both your `articleAuthor` and `articleTitle` TextViews:

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
```

Additionally, set the `layout_width` attribute to `0dp` (i.e. "match constraints") for both of these same views:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

This will cause the TextViews to be exactly as wide as the space between the left edge of the parent and the right edge of the guideline. For text that is shorter than this width, you'll get one line of left-justified text. For text that is longer than this width, you'll get multiple lines of left-justified text that wrap before the ImageView.